# How to find the value of a multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, performance

How I can search array key from multidimensional array and return found key value with parent array key if it's exist. For example I've custom array:

```
$array = [
    'type' => 'vacancy',
    'needs' => ['root' => 'active'],
    'market' => 'shopping',
    'red' => 'color', 
    'education' => 'learning',
    'fruits' => [
        'red' => 'apple',
        'cool' => 'cherry'
    ]
];
```

For example I need search key `red` from current array. As you see in this array exist 2 items with key `red`. If array have similar keys then function return example array as response:

```
[
    0 => ['red' => 'color'],
    1 => ['red' => 'apple']
]
```

If search key (example `type`) is only once inside array then response will be like this:

```
['type' => 'vacancy']
```

I tired:

```
function searchKey($key, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if($key === $k) {
            return [$k => $v];
        } elseif(is_array($v)) {
            return searchKey($key, $v);
        } elseif(is_array($k)) {
            return searchKey($key, $k);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I search key `root` from array result is correct but when I searching key `red` return `false`. How can be solved my function or has any performance methods for searching key and get result for my needs?

Comment: array depth can be increased? like child array can have another child-array in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
function findByKey($findKey, $array, $result = []) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $findKey) {
            $result[] = [$key => $value];
        }
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = findByKey($findKey, $value, $result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The idea is to use a recursive function :

1. you loop through your array
2. for each `key => value`, you check if the key is what you want : if yes, add it to the result array, else go next
3. if the value is an other array, you search inside this array if you have the key you want

Now use it :

```
$array = [
    'type' => 'vacancy',
    'needs' => ['root' => 'active'],
    'market' => 'shopping',
    'red' => 'color', 
    'education' => 'learning',
    'fruits' => [
        'red' => 'apple',
        'cool' => 'cherry'
   ]
];
```

With key `type` :

```
$result = findByKey('type', $array);

var_dump($result);
```

Output is :

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
    array(1) {
    ["type"]=>
        string(7) "vacancy"
    }
}
```

With key `red` :

```
$result = findByKey('red', $array);

var_dump($result);
```

Output is :

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        ["red"]=>
        string(5) "color"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        ["red"]=>
        string(5) "apple"
    }
}
```

Here is a link to test it : [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e26f57d08d82b888885d3a2b7e7c84ee6c54c071)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: I tested too and logic respected but only if `$result` have one item only then must return default array (no multidimensional) @Mickael Leger